# Issue any command using sftp in JSch

Tags: java, jsch

Hi I am currently using the below code line to issue commands to the remote server

`ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");`

`sftp.connect();`

`System.out.println("Current Directory: " + sftp.pwd());` <= This Line

But pwd is already be defined as a method in Class ChannelSftp, My Question is what if I want to issue some command or run any .sh file which is not a method in JSch?

Let say if I want to run : sudo /opt/bin/run.sh file.

OR is there any method which I can use to do the job

(Kindly note I have a Jump Server in between localhost and web Server. And web server can only be accessed via the jump server.So that is the reason I am not using exec or shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChannelSftp class is implementing the SFTP protocol, which is cabable of preforming FTP operations. **Executing a random command is clearly not permitted via SFTP.** What you need in this case is using a different class of the jsch lib: [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html).

Example is [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).